# How to open a PDF after running tex-file?

Tags: latex, tex

I am able to run `pdflatex` via `tex-file`, and the PDF generates just fine. How would I go about automatically opening the resultant PDF file after generation?

Comment: Are you using the AUCTeX library, or the builtin latex library, or your own custom method to generate the pdf file?

Comment: I'll have to look. I installed tex on my machine(macos) set up the tex-file command to build  using pdflatex. I haven't done anything more than that.

Comment: Try using:  `C-c C-v`  which is bound to the function `tex-view`  defined by the function `tex-define-common-keys` in the built-in `tex-mode.el` library.  This comment assumes that you are using a generic version of Emacs for OSX/MacOS without having installed the AUCTeX library.  While focus is within the *.tex buffer you can type `C-h m` to see some of the bound keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: thanks, @lawlist .. I installed AUCTeX, and it looks like C-ca does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `latex-preview-pane-mode` included in the `auctex` package.
start it whenever you want to see the pdf generated, and then as you type latex and save it you see in the other pane the result

Answer (score 0):

you can run `TeX-view` (vanilla emacs `C-c C-v`), but it might require some configuration to get working as you want it.

something like the following got me going recently:

```
;; Use emacs' pdf-tools to open PDF files:
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
      TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)

;; use synctex for click on pdf to jump to that point in tex file, and vice versa:
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)

;; Update PDF buffers after successful LaTeX runs
;; does this actually work tho?
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
          #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

if you want the pdf display to update on save, you can use `latexmk`:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (push
             '("latexmk" "latexmk -pvc -pdf --synctex=1 %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
               :help "Run latexmk on file")
             TeX-command-list)))

(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))
```

the `-pvc` flag is for continuous (live-updating) preview.

then you need to edit `~/.latexmkrc` to tell it to use pdf-tools as your previewer:

```
$pdf_previewer="emacsclient -e '(find-file-other-window %S)'";
$pdflatex='pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode %S';
$pdf_update_method = 4;
$pdf_update_command = "emacsclient -e '(with-current-buffer (find-buffer-visiting %S) (pdf-view-revert-buffer nil t))'";
```

this presumes you're running emacs in daemon/server mode (`emacsclient`).

if this works you don't have to haggle with `C-c C-c` or `C-c C-a` and answer yes three times in order to update your preview.

`syntex` and `latexmk` need to be installed, but are often bundled with tex packages.

source: some reddit, etc. harvestings i recently did.

disclaimer: i'm not running macOS.